# Issue of Bootstrap Navbar Dropdown is opening inside Navbar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have made navbar using Bootstrap 4 and also using .navbar-bottom class to add scrollbar to navbar when there are more menu items than page total width.

Now, issue is that the Bootstrap 4 navbar dropdown opens inside navbar. Check this issue as shown in below Screenshot GIF.

**Screenshot GIF**
 [Check Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjZCd.gif)

**.navbar-bottom class to add scrollbar to navbar**

```
.navbar-bottom {
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light navbar-bottom">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto pl-2">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-6" href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown1</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown2</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown3</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown4</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-6" href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        .........................................................................
        .........................................................................
        .........................................................................
        .........................................................................
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-6" href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

**This solve your problem**

The main problem is you use **dropdown** class in different **div** instade of the li element. Hope this solve your problem.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light navbar-bottom">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto pl-2">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-6" href="#">Menu Item</a></li>          
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-6" href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-6" href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```